# Online Java Compiler (Multiple File Support)

Tags: java, file, compiler-construction

I was wondering if anyone knows of a java compiler online that supports multiple files.  I have tried using the JXXX compiler(http://www.innovation.ch/java/java_compile.html) but it only has enough space for 5 source files. The program I am working on has over 10 files and the computer I am using for some reason the security program makes it unable to unzip files meaning the JDK and JRE will not work properly.  If anyone knows about an online compiler that supports 10+ java files please respond or leave a link.

Comment: You can try an online IDE: http://compilr.com/

Comment: I would copy the JDK from another computer and use it that way.

Comment: "Any answer we give you is likely to be too subjective, and will change over time." (Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine) I understand this but I am just looking for anything that works for this purpose... not your opinion of the best one...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this in the past and works well give it a try [Java Online Compiler](https://javaonlinecompiler.com/)

Comment: I have up voted this answer because I believe the Answerer should not be punished for an off topic question

Comment: I don't see where [javaonlinecompiler](https://www.javaonlinecompiler.com/) supports multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is still looking for an online Java compiler with multi-file support and is **simple to use** please look at http://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: Where's the multi-file support?

Comment: +1 because although it do not have the files concept, you can paste all your classes at the same file and it will compile all of them, and run correctly. IMO better than other that requires login... Still a good alternative now (2018).

Answer (score 3):

[Codiva.io online Java compiler](https://www.codiva.io/) supports multiple files.

1. Codiva supports multiple files and packages, sub packages.
2. You can run interactive programs.
3. Compiles as you type and has auto completion

Answer (score 2):

https://paiza.IO/ online compiler works with multiple files, supporting Java 9.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing this. First compile each 5 *.java groups at a time, and compile a 5 *.jar groups, to create a single jar, etc., etc.